# Power Apps + Power Automate + Planner + Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate, microsoft-planner

I did an app where I will send a request through power apps, it will send the information to a sharepoint list and the automate will create a task on Planner. it is running okay, but the only thing I couldn't bring from the sharepoint list were the labels. Basically, I need to insert a pink label if the task will be answered by the Finance Team, or purple label if it is going to be answered by the HR Team - it is related with the column Team Responsible on the Sharepoint list. Does anyone has a clue?

I tried some expressions that didn't work, as below:

```
contains(outputs('Get_items')?['Team Responsible'], 'Finance')

if(equals(outputs('Get_items')?['Team Responsible'],'Finance'),true,false)
```

Comment: Show us the json related to the SharePoint item and maybe we can help.

Comment: Please update your question with a little more info, perhaps share a screengrab of your the relevant flow steps. Is the Team Responsible a `Choice` column?